# Are two generic filters in a common generic extension?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $M$ be a countable transitive set. Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is a forcing in $M$. Let $G$ and $H$ be two generic filters for $\mathbb{P}$ over $M$.

My questions are:

Is there a forcing $\mathbb{Q}$ and a generic $K$ for this forcing over $M$ such that $G,H \in M[K]$?

If the answer is yes, can this $\mathbb{Q}$ be chosen to depend only on $\mathbb{P}$ and not the filters $G$ and $H$?

---

If $M$ and $H$ are mutually $\mathbb{P}$-generic then by definition, $\mathbb{Q}$ can be $\mathbb{P}\times\mathbb{P}$. So the main difficultly is the case when the two filters are not mutually generic.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: You might also be interested in this related question on automatic mutual genericity: http://mathoverflow.net/q/222602/1946.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a $\mathbb{Q}$ may not exist. Indeed, we can find two reals $x,y$, both Cohen over $M$, such that no extension of $M$ with the same ordinals contains both $x,y$. The idea is to take a real coding the entire model $M$ and then disguise it by breaking it up between the two Cohen reals.

Joel David Hamkins has a manuscript [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01074) describing the argument, which he attributes to Woodin. He also identifies a large class of posets that exhibit the same kind of non-amalgability phenomenon (any $\mathbb{P}$ which is not $|\mathbb{P}|$-cc below any condition will have such incompatible generics).

Comment: There's a simpler proof: just take two Cohen reals whose symmetric difference is a code for a well-ordering longer than the height of $M$. If $z$ is a real coding such a well-order, then both $\{x: x$ Cohen over $M\}$ and $\{x\Delta z: x$ Cohen over $M\}$ are comeager, so there is a $y$ which is Cohen over $M$ and such that $y\Delta z$ is also Cohen over $M$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That's a nice proof. It seems to me that Woodin's argument is just a more hands-on version of yours, where he also basically proves the two sets of reals are comeagre along the way.